Tailwind.css responsive classNames are applied to HTML elements but the actual classes are not sent to the browser
I'm working on a project that uses Next.js and Tailwind.css. I created a utility function for structure large classNames with breakpoints in a more readable way.
The function is named responsive and takes an object that can contain a classValue to apply for each breakpoint:
type Breakpoint = 'initial' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl' | '2xl';

function prefixClassValue(prefix: Breakpoint, classValue: ClassValue) {
  return (
    classValue &&
    cn(classValue)
      .split(' ')
      .map((className) => `${prefix}:${className}`)
      .join(' ')
  );
}

export function responsive({
  initial,
  sm,
  md,
  lg,
  xl,
  '2xl': xl2,
}: Partial<Record<Breakpoint, ClassValue>>) {
  return cn(
    initial,
    prefixClassValue('sm', sm),
    prefixClassValue('md', md),
    prefixClassValue('lg', lg),
    prefixClassValue('xl', xl),
    prefixClassValue('2xl', xl2),
  );
}

The problem comes when the classes applied to breakpoints larger than initial are not sended to the browser. The HTML elements have the correct classes, but the classes itself are not included in the layout.css file sent to the browser.
I tried to render this grid using the responsive function:
<div
  className={responsive({
  initial: 'grid grid-cols-1 gap-2',
  sm: 'grid-cols-3 gap-4',
  md: 'grid-cols-4',
  lg: 'gap-5',
  xl: 'grid-cols-5',
})}
>{/*...*/}</div>

The output of this function call is grid grid-cols-1 gap-2 sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4 md:grid-cols-4 lg:gap-5 xl:grid-cols-5, and the rendered div is:
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-2 sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4 md:grid-cols-4 lg:gap-5 xl:grid-cols-5">...</div>

Although the classes are correctly applied, the classes itself aren't appearing in dev tools and the breakpoints are not working.
I've tried different function variations and nothing worked. If I put all the classes directly to className prop, it works perfectly. I don't know why this happens. Any thoughts on this are welcome.
Thank you for you time!


Next.js version 14.2.3
Tailwind.css version 3.4.3


As per the documentation:

The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
Don’t construct class names dynamically
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
Always use complete class names
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>


You would need to pass full class name strings, like:
<div
  className={`
    grid grid-cols-1 gap-2
    sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4
    md:grid-cols-4
    lg:gap-5
    xl:grid-cols-5
  `}
>{/*...*/}</div>

